# ASP.Net Prevent Timeout for Long Running Process

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.net page that uploads a CSV file and then does some processing on it.  This can possibly take up to 10 minutes to complete for a large file.  However, the process ends up timing out.

I have added the following to the web.config:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200" maxRequestLength="104856"  />
```

Also, I have gone into IIS and set the Connection Timeout to 1,200 seconds.  I also set the ASP script timeout to 1,200 seconds in IIS as well.

However, after approximately 2 minutes the web log file stops getting updated.

Any ideas on what is causing this to stop processing?  What other timeout settings am I missing?

THanks!

Comment: Are there HTTP timeout exceptions in the Event Viewer?

Answer (score 3):

I usually try to avoid long running requests.  Are you sure this is the best way to do this?  In the past I have either:

- Uploaded the document through the web app, but not acted on it.  Basically upload it to a watched folder and then process it through a separate process.
- Use an alternate method to upload the document (ftp usually).  Again, process the file with a separate process.

Probably not the answer you were looking for, but it might be a better solution to your problem?